# PDO: MySQL server has gone away, can't catch exception

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**General Description**
I'm working a chatsystem using websockets (Ratchet). The chat works perfectly fine, but I'm having some issue with my database class.

**The Problem**
During development, the chatsystem obviously isn't visited a lot. This causes the MySQL server to close the connection eventually. To solve that issue, I've written some exception handlers to reconnect to the MySQL server. But somehow this doesn't work. Here's the bare minimum of how my code looks like:

```
<?php

Class Database {
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;

    private $dbh;
    private $error;

    private $stmt;

    public function __construct(){

        if($this->dbh === null){
            $this->reconnect();
        }
    }

    private function reconnect(){
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        // Set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => false,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        // Catch any errors
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            return $this->error;
        }
    }

    /* Execute query */
    public function execute(){
        try{
            return $this->stmt->execute();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->reconnect();

            try{
                return $this->stmt->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
                return $this->error;
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course there are many more simular methods, but those are not important.

The error I'm being presented with is the following:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in /var/www/clients/client1/web4/web/src/Pdo.php:43
>   Stack trace:
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web4/web/src/Pdo.php(43): PDOStatement->execute()

That error points to `return $this->stmt->execute();` in the `execute()` method above.

1. How is it possible that the error is telling me *"Uncaught PDOException"* while I'm clearly catching it?
2. How is the MySQL server even able to disconnect while I'm not using a persistent connection? `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,`

Comment: Are you in a namespace? `catch (\PDOException $e)` perhaps?

Comment: @miken32 Yes, I actually am. Though I'm using `use \PDO;` at the top. I thought that was sufficient?

Comment: That's a different class than `PDOException` though.

Comment: @miken32 Hmm that makes sense. I'll implement that and see how it works out. For now I at least solved the problem client side by doing a couple of re-connects through JS (allowing the MySQL server to connect again). At least that works, just prefer to prevent to the problem in the first place

Comment: [mysql gone away error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html). If its a large query or contains large blobs, then `max_allowed_packet ` size being to small is a likely cause.

Comment: @danblack Thanks for your input. I've done my research before asking. There's no large packet or something like that. This is just the login part where a username is verified. That's all :) I know the reason for the error (no queries for several hours). It's not the error that I'm worried about. More the "why" my fix doesn't work.

Comment: I had the same problem with almost identical code and eventually resolved it by putting the `try { ... new PDO ...} catch { ... }` in a `for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)` loop. I probably could have got away with 2 rather than 3 but haven't gone back to test it - too many other bugs to fix!

Comment: @Nick Thanks. I actually had the same idea at some point. That perhaps the time between the reconnect attempt and the execution of a query was simply too fast for MySQL to reconnect. But, as my exception isn't even caught in the first place, I'll have to resolve that issue first. Unfortunetely I don't know how to force a "MySQL server gone away" error to verify miken's tip. So I'm just letting it run untill I can verify it. See if at least it's being caught now. If it is, and the problem isn't solved, I'll definitely try your tip. Thanks

Comment: @icecub forgot to mention - for some reason (lost in the sands of time I'm afraid) I had to change the catch to Exception to get it to work properly

Comment: @Nick Ye, catching with plain Exception will always work. Kind of the "if all else failes.." solution, haha. I'll make sure to post an update once I have more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As determined in the comments, you're running this code within another namespace. This means that `catch (PDOException $e)` is actually `catch (\Your\Namespace\PDOException $e)` so will not work. You'll either need to prefix the class with a leading backslash to put it in the global namespace:

```
catch(\PDOException $e){
    $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    return $this->error;
}
```

Or `use` the class at the beginning of your code.

```
use \PDOException;
```

Comment: It seems you were absolutely right. After running the websocket for 17 hours and trying to login again, the exception caught on perfectly fine and reastablished the MySQL connection without any issues or errors. Thanks a lot!